# How to add an image to the right of rows in TableView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I want to add an arrow to the right of each row in TableView on iPhone. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just worked it out:

```
-(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //add action here
}
```

A blue arrow will show up to the right of each row.

Answer (score 3):

You mean the default arrow (a chevron) that lots of apps have?

```
UITableViewCell *myCell = ...; //GET a cell from somewhere.
myCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```